# How to parse a large JSON file efficiently in Python?

Tags: python, json

I have a file that contains an array of JSON objects. The file is over 1GB, so I can't load it into memory all at once. I need to parse each of the individual objects. I tried using `ijson`, but that will load the entire array as one object, effectively doing the same thing as a simple `json.load()` would.

Is there another way how to do it?

Edit: Nevermind, just use `ijson.items()` and set the prefix parameter to `"item"`.

Comment: How did you write that file in the first place?

Comment: I didn't; it was given to me.

Answer (score 3):

You can parse the JSON file once to find the positions of each level-1 separator, i.e. a comma that is part of the top-level object, and then divide the file into sections indicated by these positions. For example:

```
{"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": "Hello, World!", "c": {"d": 4, "e": 5}}
        ^      ^            ^        ^             ^
        |      |            |        |             |
     level-2   |         quoted      |          level-2
               |                     |
            level-1               level-1
```

Here we want to find the level-1 commas, that separate the objects which are contained by the top-level object. We can use a generator which parses the JSON stream and keeps track of descending into and stepping out of nested objects. When it encounters a level-1 comma that is not quoted it yields the corresponding position:

```
def find_sep_pos(stream, *, sep=','):
    level = 0
    quoted = False  # handling strings in the json
    backslash = False  # handling quoted quotes
    for pos, char in enumerate(stream):
        if backslash:
            backslash = False
        elif char in '{[':
            level += 1
        elif char in ']}':
            level -= 1
        elif char == '"':
            quoted = not quoted
        elif char == '\\':
            backslash = True
        elif char == sep and not quoted and level == 1:
            yield pos
```

Used on the example data above, this would give `list(find_sep_pos(example)) == [15, 37]`.

Then we can divide the file into sections that correspond to the separator positions and load each section individually via `json.loads`:

```
import itertools as it
import json

with open('example.json') as fh:
    # Iterating over `fh` yields lines, so we chain them in order to get characters.
    sep_pos = tuple(find_sep_pos(it.chain.from_iterable(fh)))
    fh.seek(0)  # reset to the beginning of the file
    stream = it.chain.from_iterable(fh)
    opening_bracket = next(stream)
    closing_bracket = dict(('{}', '[]'))[opening_bracket]
    offset = 1  # the bracket we just consumed adds an offset of 1
    for pos in sep_pos:
        json_str = (
            opening_bracket
            + ''.join(it.islice(stream, pos - offset))
            + closing_bracket
        )
        obj = json.loads(json_str)  # this is your object
        next(stream)  # step over the separator
        offset = pos + 1  # adjust where we are in the stream right now
        print(obj)
    # The last object still remains in the stream, so we load it here.
    obj = json.loads(opening_bracket + ''.join(stream))
    print(obj)
```

Comment: Your parser doesn't account for quoted quotes, like in `"foo\",\"bar"`.

Comment: @chepner Thanks for the hint. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

2 options

1. Parse in CLI using tools like JQ and then take it to Python for further processing.
2. Parse using PySpark (community data bricks gives you free space)

[JQ how to use](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/parse-json-easily-like-a-pro-9decef2fd132)